# Typescript: assign one type to many variables

Tags: typescript, types

I am new to TypeScript, I got following predefined type:

```js
type SC = StyledComponent<any, any>;
```

in my script I have tons of variables using this type:

```js
    ColorBarItemHoverArray!: Array<SC>;
    AdjustColorContainer!: SC;
    HandleHover!: SC;
    DivContainer!: SC;
    ATag!: SC;
    SpanTag1!: SC;
    SpanTag2!: SC;
    SpanTag3!: SC;
    SpanTag4!: SC;
    StyledLabelSide!: SC;
    StyledRangeSide!: SC;
    StyledInputSide!: SC;
    StyledLabelRatio!: SC;
    StyledRangeRatio!: SC;
    StyledInputRatio!: SC;
    StyledLabelAngle!: SC;
    StyledRangeAngle!: SC;
    StyledInputAngle!: SC;
    StyledLabelSpeed!: SC;
    StyledRangeSpeed!: SC;
    StyledInputSpeed!: SC;
    StyledButtonInverse!: SC;
    StyledButtonAbstract!: SC;
    StyledButtonArrow!: SC;
    ArrowLeft!: SC;
    ArrowRight!: SC;
```

is there a better way to write these?

Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're defining tons of variables all with the same type, that is usually a signal that you need to either give them better types, or refactor and break things up.

By using `<any, any>`, you are losing most of the benefits of Typescript.
Why not define each variable in a correct manner, then they will not all be the same vague `any` type?

Also, you can help yourself slightly by creating a new type - by rearranging your list, I can see it can be grouped like so:

```
    StyledLabelSide!: SC;
    StyledLabelRatio!: SC;
    StyledLabelAngle!: SC;
    StyledLabelSpeed!: SC;

    StyledInputSide!: SC;
    StyledInputRatio!: SC;
    StyledInputAngle!: SC;
    StyledInputSpeed!: SC;

    StyledRangeSide!: SC;
    StyledRangeRatio!: SC;
    StyledRangeAngle!: SC;
    StyledRangeSpeed!: SC;
```

You could define a type for an object with the fields `side`, `ratio`, `angle` &  `speed`, and then you can just define three variables (`StyledLabel`, `StyledInput` & `StyledRange`) instead of twelve.

Comment: ok, I guess there is no way to assign one to many yet.

Comment: It's unlikely that there will be a way - it's bad practice to have so many variables like that, with no definition but just a type with no hierarchy. Also makes it harder to redefine the types if you do them all at once.